# Keep silverlight video in full screen in a dual monitor configuration

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight video playing in the second monitor attached to my laptop. I want to work on my laptop screen and want silverlight video to remain in full screen mode.

Is there some configuration change i need to do on my laptop to make this work?

Comment: this is not a programming related question

Comment: Yes, i agree this is not a programming related question, but more like a configuration question. I cannot seem to get this solved though.

Comment: Thank you @Giacomo, i have posted the question to superuser.com

Comment: you welcome, I just hope you'll get some good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you need to upgrade to Silverlight 4:

[New features in Silverlight 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-be/library/dd772166.aspx#featuresin4)

> Full-Screen Support
>
> Silverlight 4 enables applications to remain in full-screen mode when another application is active.

---

Update for programmers looking to check/enable this:

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.FullScreenOptions = System.Windows.Interop.FullScreenOptions.StaysFullScreenWhenUnfocused;
```